# Lua emulating the require function

Tags: lua, world-of-warcraft

In the embeded lua environment (World of Warcraft - WoW) is missing the `require` function.

I want port one existing lua source code ([an great OO-library](https://github.com/fperrad/lua-Coat/tree/master/src)) for the use it in the WoW. The library itself is relatively small (approx 8 small files) but of course it heavily uses the `require`.

World of Warcraft loads files and libraries by defining it in an XML file, like:

```
<Ui xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.blizzard.com/wow/ui/">
    <Script file="LibOne.lua"/>
    <Script file="LibTwo.lua"/>
</Ui>
```

but i don't know how the low level library manipulation is done in the WoW.

AFAIK in the WoW is missing even the `package.` table too. :(

So the question(s): For me, the streamlined way would be write an function which will emulate the `require` function using the interface available in WoW. The question is how. Could someone give me some directions?

Or as alternative, for the porting the mentioned existing source to WoW, I need replace the `require Some.Other.Module` lines in the lua sources to something what WoW will understand. What is the equivalent/replacement for such `require Some.Module` in the WoW?

How the WoW handles modules/libraries at low-level?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could merge all files into one using one of the various amalgamation scripts, e.g. [`amalg`](https://github.com/siffiejoe/lua-amalg). Then you can load this file and a stub that implements the `require` function using the usual WoW way:

```
<Ui xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.blizzard.com/wow/ui/">
    <Script file="RequireStub.lua"/>
    <Script file="AllModules.lua"/><!-- amalgamated Lua modules -->
    <Script file="YourCode.lua"/>
</Ui>
```

The file `RequireStub.lua` could look like:

```
package = {}
local preload, loaded = {}, {
  string = string,
  debug = debug,
  package = package,
  _G = _G,
  io = io,
  os = os,
  table = table,
  math = math,
  coroutine = coroutine,
}
package.preload, package.loaded = preload, loaded


function require( mod )
  if not loaded[ mod ] then
    local f = preload[ mod ]
    if f == nil then
      error( "module '"..mod..[[' not found:
       no field package.preload[']]..mod.."']", 1 )
    end
    local v = f( mod )
    if v ~= nil then
      loaded[ mod ] = v
    elseif loaded[ mod ] == nil then
      loaded[ mod ] = true
    end
  end
  return loaded[ mod ]
end
```

This should emulate enough of the `package` library to get you a working `require` that loads modules in the amalgamated file. Different amalgamation scripts might need different bits from `package`, though, so you probably will have to take a look at the generated Lua source code.

And in the specific case of `Coat` you might need to implement stubs for other Lua functions as well. E.g. I've seen that `Coat` uses the `debug` library ...

Comment: This code is really hard for to me understand. What is the purpose of all those variables inside of `loaded`? Can you go more into detail?

Comment: @Hatefiend: `package.loaded` caches all loaded/required modules. The ones listed above are the modules from Lua's standard library. In "normal" Lua they are available via `require` from `package.loaded` and as global variables. In WoW there are only the global variables, so we have to fill `package.loaded` ourselves.

Answer (score 2):

WoW environment doesn't have `dofile` or any other means to read external files at all. You need to explicitly mention all files that must be loaded in `.toc` file or `.xml` referenced from `.toc`.

You can then write your own implementation of `require` to maintain compatibility with your library, which would be quite trivial as it would only need to parse module name and retrieve it's content from `modules.loaded` table, but you'd still need to alter original source to make files register in that table and you'll need to manually arrange all files into correct order of loading.

Alternatively you can rearrange files into separate WoW-addons and use its own built-in `Dependencies`/`OptionalDeps` facilities or popular [`LibStub`](http://wow.gamepedia.com/LibStub) framework to handle loading order automatically.

Comment: So, the `modules.loaded` table is available? Because the `package.*` tables are missing (AFAIK - it is used by the `require` in the "standard" lua).

Comment: No, it is not. But it is just a regular table. It is just a convention of `require` framework to use it. You can make and fill it yourself.

Comment: Does WoW environment have `loadstring` ?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: It [seems that way](http://wowprogramming.com/docs/api/loadstring).

Comment: Yes, but it is patched to only allow plain source and not bytecode.